# java web application profilling local on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I have a web application build using J2EE technology, now i want to profile and monitor its performance, like showing those methods,queries which are making application to run slow. Can anyone suggest a good tool to do this job.

I am using ubuntu 12 os, jdk 1.7 , eclipse 4.4.2,tomcat 7 and also using ANT build.xml to build my web application.

I have tried using visualVM  ,jprofiler but all those good for a java application. please suggest a good open source software.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't worked with it, but it was the first what comes in my mind: [jeeObserver](http://www.jeeobserver.com/)

Comment: I installed jprofiler and its working fine. And i ll check jeeObserver too thank you.